# Why is there `pip3.10.exe` in `Python311\Scripts`

Tags: python, pip, python-3.11

As you can see below, after I installed `Python 3.11`, I came to the realization that running `pip3.10 freeze` did not list me the packages I had in my `Python 3.10.2` but those of my `Python 3.11`. This is explained by the fact that in `Python311\Scripts` I have both `pip3.10.exe` and `pip3.11.exe`. Is there a reason? When I want to `pip install` or do `pip freeze` with `pip3.10` I need to use the absolute path now.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why that is, so I can't answer. But as a sidenote, you might be interested in [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage multiple Python versions without going insane. If you also need multiple virtual environments per Python version, it has a plugin ([pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv)) to handle that too.

Comment: Oh yes I do use virtual environments quite often, it's just that for quick tests I have messy basic environments that I can (usually) call easily with pip3.9, pip3.10, pip3.11, etc ... and I can't really anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a pip bug, I don't understand the details exactly but when pip tried to  match to the correct Python version it was only accounting for single-digit version numbers, resulting in this weird behavior. [Perhaps it is better explained in this thread on github.](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/98682)

To summarize that thread ([from user uranusjr](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/98682#issuecomment-1291650123)):

> pip contains logic to specially fix pipX.Y (and easy_install-X.Y) entry points to correctly match the Python version, but that logic only accounts for single-digit version numbers and doesn’t work with 3.10 upwards.

This was fixed with pip version 22.3.1 [(Also seen on this github thread)](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/11547#issuecomment-1304575112), and from what I can tell doesn't occur anymore when using python 3.11.1.

Comment: I might just delete my Python 3.11.0 and get Python 3.11.1 then. I don't need more than one Python per 3.X